# Cache XMLProvider generated model(s)

Tags: f#, type-providers

Using `XMLProvider` from the `FSharp.Data` package like:

```
type internal MyProvider = XmlProvider<Sample = "C:\test.xml">
```

The `test.xml` file contains a total of 151,838 lines which makes up 15 types.

Working in the same project as the type declaration `MyProvider` is a pain, as it seems the `XmlProvider` is triggered everytime I hit `CTRL`+`SPACE` (`Edit.CompleteWord`) - and therefore regenerates all the models, which can take up to 10sec.

Is there any known work around, or setting to cache the generated models from `XmlProvider`?

Comment: I'm afraid we do not have any caching mechanism for the inferred schema - but it sounds like something that should not be too hard to add - open a GitHub issue if you'd be interested in contributing. Aside from that, I guess simplifying the sample XML is (currently) the only way to address this.

Comment: @TomasPetricek, Thanks. Could you please make your comment an answer, so that I can accept it? :-)

Comment: Thanks, answer posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid F# Data does not currently have any caching mechanism for the inferred schema. It sounds like something that should not be too hard to add - if anyone is interested in contributing, please [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues) to start the discussion!

My recommendation for the time being would be to try to simplify the sample XML, so that it is shorter and contains just a few representative records of all the different kinds.